# How to sum values populated from the database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, sql-server-2012, dynamic-tables

I have a dynamic table being populated from the database. My code is as below :

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="tb">
  <thead>
    <tr style="BACKGROUND-COLOR: DarkGrey ">
      <th colspan="5" style="text-align:Center;">Objectives</th>
    </tr>
    <tr class="tr-header">
      <th style="text-align:Center;width:10%;">ID</th>
      <th colspan="2">Targets</th>
      <th style="text-align:Center;width:1%;" rowspan="2">Weightage %</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th> </th>
      <th> </th>
      <th style="width:10%;"> Date </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody
  <?PHP
  $myquery = "select subtotals,Serial_Number,Targets,Weightage, row_number,edit_details
              from Table1 WHERE Serial_Number='$Serial_Number' ORDER BY Row_Number asc";
  $fetched = sqlsrv_query($conn, $myquery);
  if ($fetched === false) {
    die(print_r(sqlsrv_errors(), true));
  }
  while ($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    $Weightage = $res['Weightage'];
    $Targets = $res['Targets'];
    $Row_Number = $res['row_number'];
    $subtotals = $res['subtotals'];
    ?>
    <tr id="<?php //echo $id  ?>" class="tredit">
      <td class="edittbl">
        <b><input type="text" name="ID[]" class="ASDF form-control" id="Row<?php echo $Row_Number ?>" value="<?php echo $Row_Number; ?>" readonly></input></b>
      </td>                                               
      <?PHP
      if ($Objectives == "SubTotal") {
        ?>
        <td class="edittbl" colspan="3">
          <b><input type="text" name="Subtotal[]" class=" ASDF form-control" value="<?php echo $Objectives; ?>" style="text-align:center;" readonly ></input></b>
        </td>   
        <td class="edittbl">
          <b><input type="text" name="SubTotal_Weightage[]" class="ASDF form-control" value="<?php echo $Weightage; ?>" readonly></input></b>
        </td>                                               
        <?PHP
      } else {
        ?>
        <td class="edittbl">
          <input type="text" name="Targets[]" class="ASDF form-control" value="<?php echo $Targets; ?>" ></input>
        </td> 
        <td class="edittbl">
          <input type="text" name="Weightage[]" class="ASDF form-control" value="<?php echo $Weightage; ?>"></input>
        </td>
      <?PHP } ?>
      </tr>                   
    <?PHP } ?>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I am trying to do a auto calculate on sub-totals when the values change, such that when the weightage changes, the sub-totals auto calculate and give the new value.

[image: Calculation Image]

These weightages are dynamic, and the subtotal's donot have a fixed position. How do I ensure that if there's any change in the first four it changes the 1st sub-total and if there's any change in the 2nd and 3rd one it changes the 2nd sub-total?

Would appreciate any suggestion.

Comment: Very first point. No two inputs can have *same id in same page*. Check it. `id="Row<?php echo $Row_Number ?>"` every input having same id.

Answer (score 0):

Add onchange attribute on input tag and call js function and do your calculation there:
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onchange.asp

Another way to do that is js change function. Bind it with your input
https://api.jquery.com/change/

Comment: binding it with the input is okay and can be done but how will I know that the 1st few should add up to the sub-total and the next ones to the 2nd sub-total?

Answer (score 0):

First, why not separate the controller logic and model from the view? It'll make your code cleaner.
I assume weightage will changed based on user input via a form field according to the code snippet you pasted. I honestly don't understand how you calculate subtotals but I'm thinking you should implement an AJAX style solution for this such that when the weightage changes, a request is sent to the model to recalculate the subtotal, either via fetching it from the database or from some form of Logic.